# Regex Ignore Comments In Java

Tags: regex, eclipse

I can't seem to find a concise answer on this and as I know very little about regex, I feel the easiest option is to ask.

I am trying to count lines of code in eclipse, which I can do, but it includes the comments.

Basically, my regex pattern is "\n"

Pretty basic, yes, but try as I might, I can't seem to figure out a way to ignore a line starting with "//"

I've tried [^(//)] but that seems to count every "/". I've tried the same thing without the delimiter: "\"

Any ideas, even if you just point me in the right direction, my google searches didn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: Do you also want to count blank lines? What about Javadoc comments?

Comment: You can’t do this with a regex.  You need to use a parsing module and count statements, not lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) here. For your case code like this will work:

```
String str = "Line1\n" +
"/Line2\n" +
"//Line3\n" +
"Line4\n" +
" // Line5\n" +
"Line6\n";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("^(?!\\s*//)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
matcher matcher = pt.matcher(str);
int c=0;
while (matcher.find()) c++;
System.out.println("# of lines: " + c);
```

#### Output

```
# of lines: 4
```

`(?!\\s*//)` is negative lookahead that is saying match only if a line **doesn't** start with `0 or more spaces followed by //` 
As you can see there are 2 lines above starting with comment `//` hence they are not counted.
Also it is important to use `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag here to make every line recognize start of line character `^`.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified regex, will improve if you need more:

```
^//
```

Anything in `[]` is a character class, which means match one of the symbols within it. Also adding `^` is the inverse of that and is not the same as a `^` outside which mathces the beginning of the string.

You can also do something like:

```
^[^/][^/].*
```

to match lines not starting with `//`

Comment: +1 for bothering to explain instead of presenting a complete, complicated solution accompanied only by the worse "Try this:". An alternative to the second one it `^(?!//)` (negative lookahead, doesn't actually consume the first two characters).

Comment: @delnan yes I would prefer that, but wanted to keep it simple, as the OP is new to regex.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways and other tools to count lines of code, for instance a test coverage tool or (I don't know if this still works with the newest version): http://metrics.sourceforge.net/

If you just ignore `//`, then you will still count the `package` and `import` declarations along with multi-line comments such as:

```
/**
 * Javadoc
 */
```

or brackets that sit alone on lines like:

```
while(...)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with eclipse, but if it has lookahead this should do it:

```
\n(?!//)
```

Answer (score 0):

^\s*(?!//)\S.*$

Highlights any line that starts ("^") with any number of spaces (\s*"), then does not start a comment ("(?!//)"), then has a non-space character ("\S"), then has any number of any characters until end of the line (".*$").